# Should i have to put the copy protection to my Application if i have given Android Licensing to my Application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, google-play

I have added the Android Licensing to my Application. to check for the application licensing.
There is also one option like copy protection during uploading the application on Android Market.
So if i have Implemented the Android Licensing to My apps, then should i have to give it to copy protection ?
Is it necessary to give copy protection ?
If i have not given copy protection and have given Android Licensing to My Application, then user can be able to copy it to anoter device. But should it be able to install in to another device ? I have to know about it..
So Please let me know what steps i have to take ?
Should i have to give copy protection on if i have given Licensing or not ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taken from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html):
**Replacement for Copy Protection**

Android Market Licensing is a flexible, secure mechanism for controlling access to your applications. **It effectively replaces the Copy Protection mechanism offered on Android Market** and gives you wider distribution potential for your applications.

- A limitation of the legacy Copy Protection mechanism on Android Market is that applications using it can be installed only on compatible devices that provide a secure internal storage environment. For example, a copy-protected application cannot be downloaded from Market to a device that provides root access, and the application cannot be installed to a device's SD card.
- With Android Market licensing, you can move to a license-based model in which access is not bound to the characteristics of the host device, but to your publisher account on Android Market and the licensing policy that you define. Your application can be installed and controlled on any compatible device on any storage, including SD card.

Although no license mechanism can completely prevent all unauthorized use, the licensing service lets you control access for most types of normal usage, across all compatible devices, locked or unlocked, that run Android 1.5 or higher version of the platform.

Comment: ok. But if i havent give the copy protection and have give the android licensing to my application, Then will that application be able to copy and install successfully to another device from one device after download it once from the android market ? i am saying that just because i have uploaded the Paid application to android market. So i am worried about to being copy of that application.

Comment: Because in One application i found that, If i have given copy protection that user have to Clear all the User data from its device to make it run again after successfully download it from market.

Comment: @iDroid Explorer: before "selling" an application and protect it you should carefully read Google docs, don't you think? If you read carefully [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html) you see that your app talks with Android market app inside the phone and this talks (with higher privileges) with Android licensing service on the web. Well, anyone can install your app, but according to your policy (you MUST set one, even the default) licensins service will be called and a valid license is checked. Read and you'll find which phone params are used by default.

Comment: I have read it before uploading my application. But i want to know one thing is if i have not given copy protection and if any one have downloaded it. Then should it be installed successfully to another device which havent downloaded it from android market, but have copy the apk file from other device. but it have licensing o that application.

Comment: @iDroid Explorer: if someone buys your APK and then give it to a friend and this friend installs the APK on its phone, it simply doesn't work, because Android Market does not recognize a valid license for that phone. You could "trap" a not valid license and do what you please, but read carefully Google guide lines.

Comment: @Makro : ok ok. Thanks for the Support and answers. I got the point. Perhaps it happend because i have given the copy protection to my application.

Answer (score 2):

Google's "app filtering" is *VERY* buggy... and getting worse.

Many of our apps are listed "not available on this device"... even when the OS version is ok... the device is NOT on our "exclude list"... the device has absolutely NO screen-size or screen-resolution limits.   Google still claims "not available on this device".

I'm *RUNNING* the apps... as we speak... right on several of the "forbidden devices".  They install and run 100% fine.   But they are forever listed as "not for this device" in the store.

Great way to sell apps.   Users can't download them on 100 different fully legal devices.